# How google url with # works

Tags: url, search, google-search

How the URL like https://www.google.co.in/#q=harry+potter works?
As per my understanding anything after the # is not sent to the server. 
Now if we paste the above URL in browser then it get the search page for Harry Potter.
As per my understanding when one request the above URL a request will be sent to server and since the search term "Happy Potter" is after the '#' it won't be sent to the server. So server wont have anyway to determine what to search? So then how it works. Does browser does anything special ?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, the server does not see your search term.

It's a client side JavaScript that is executed upon page load and inspects the url. It then executes an XHR request with the search term appended in a way that is visible to the server (`https://www.google.co.in/search?q=harry+potter&...`).

Reload the page with JavaScript disabled and you will see that you are getting the regular page without pre-filled search box and results.